# What other materials besides plastic can be used to produce PDGA discs?

Tags: equipment, disc-golf

I know that the majority of companies use various blends of plastic, and Vibram is the only one who uses rubber (as far as I'm aware). Is there anything in writing from the PDGA that prohibits certain materials from being used in disc manufacturing? (Metals, cloth, wood, for example.)

I understand that the PDGA tests each disc before approving them for tournament play, and each disc needs to pass tests regarding flexibility, but if a disc manufacturer could pass those tests with metal or wood, would they be PDGA approved?

Answer (score 2):

The [PDGA Technical Standards, Rev. 5/14/2014](http://www.pdga.com/documents/pdga-technical-standards-manufacturers-guidelines) contains this language on the material permissible for discs manufactured for PDGA competition:

> (2) be made of solid, non-magnetic plastic material, without any inflatable components. Electronic
>   components may be embedded/inserted with none of its metal components externally exposed.

"Plastic" is a pretty broad term.  It generally refers to a non-metallic material that can be molded.  Plastic can be based on natural or synthetic materials, and the [material that Vibram uses](http://www.vibramdiscgolf.com/discs.html#xlink) is a natural rubber-based plastic compound.

I would guess that a [molded wood-based material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood-plastic_composite) would be permissible.

Metal seems to be explicitly rejected.  There can be electronic components inside, but no metal exposed externally.  Part of this rule, I'm sure, is to prevent the disc from being magnetized.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there *magnetic* plastic materials?

Comment: @DA. Indeed, there are [plastic magnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_magnet).

Comment: whoa! Today, I learned something!